400 error when Sending an axios post request to Spring backend
I have this data that I want to send over to a backend endpoint to perform some database operations, now the issue is when I check the network, I can see that request does get initiated and does contain the data as it's request body, but somehow it tells me that it the endpoint didn't recieve a parametre when it's literally in the request body.
This is the function that sends the data, it takes it from the value attribute inside a button.
function sendThefknData(mangaId) {
        axios.post('/saveManga', {
            mangaId: mangaId
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Manga saved successfully:', response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('There was an error saving the manga:', error);
            });
    }


this is here is the controller endpoint
@PostMapping("/saveManga")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveManga(@RequestParam("mangaId") String mangaId, HttpSession session) {
        try {
            Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");
            if (userId == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("User not logged in.");
            }

            System.out.println("Manga ID: " + mangaId);
            System.out.println("User ID from session: " + userId);

            usermangainfo.insertUserMangas(userId, mangaId);

            return ResponseEntity.ok("Manga saved successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Error saving manga: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

I honestly have no idea what the issue would be, I tried googling and tried my luck with chatgpt but to no avail.Network

You should include the request in your question, for example as Copy as cUrl from the browser dev console network tab. That makes it much clearer what the backend will actually have to work with.

What is the error?

Hey you are sending request param in wrong way. Use the below
axios.post(/saveManga?mangaId=${mangaId})
this should work.

Ok I think this fixed it, it went from that error to a generique sql error, though I am not quite sure why my previous axios post wasn't working, to me it looks the same as anything in the body parametre will then be added to the url.

request param and request body are two different things in your previous code you were expecting request param in api but you were sending request body.
Just have a look on request param and request body and you will get to know :)

The documentation for RequestParam states:

In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query parameters, form data, and parts in multipart requests.

But if I'm not mistaken you are probably sending a json body. That's why the parameter is not found by your backend. It expects a form parameter called mangaId in its current implementation.
You can either send form data using axios or you change the spring implementation to make use of the RequestBody.
